# How can C# cast a generic of type T to T?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics, singleton

In the book "Game development patterns with Unity", there is this piece of code

```
public class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : Component 
{
  private static T _instance;

  public static T Instance => _instance;

  public virtual void Awake()        
  {
    if (_instance == null)            
    {
      _instance = this as T;      
    }
    else
    {
      Destroy(gameObject);            
    }        
  }
}
```

How can C# cast an instance of Singleton<T> to T?

Comment: Can you share from where did you find this code?

Comment: `this as T` doesn't make a lot of sense. `this` will never be a `T`, it's always a `Singleton<T>`.

Comment: @Chetan Game development patterns with Unity by David Baron, chapter 4

Comment: You might want to re-look at the code of Chapter 4 that book.. is it not the same as you shared here. If you refer to the correct code, you might have your doubt resolved. You can find the correct code [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Game-Development-Patterns-with-Unity-2021-Second-Edition/blob/main/Assets/Chapters/Chapter04/Implementing%20a%20Game%20Manager%20with%20the%20Singleton/Scripts/Singleton.cs)

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I still don't understand how `_instance = this as T` work, since, as gunr2171 said, `this` is `Singleton<T>`

Answer (score 0):

The Singleton class is not meant to be used on its own. You can inherit from Singleton the class you want to create as a singleton pattern like GameManager and use it.

This is example.

```
public class GameManager : Singleton<GameManager>
{
    public void ManagerMethod()
    {
        // your code.
    }
}
```

```
public class MyClass
{
    void Do()
    {
        GameManager.Instance.ManagerMethod();
    }
}
```